# How do I access / manipulate an element within a Flux / Mono

Tags: spring-webflux

I need to access a method inside a class, which is inside the Mono. How do I do this?

I have:

```
 public Mono<LegalPerson> find(Long id) {
        return Optional.of(repository.findById(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("Error"));
    }
```

And here is my problem:

```
   public void update(Mono<LegalPerson> legalPersonJson) {
        var legalPersonDB = find(legalPersonJson.map(legalPerson -> legalPerson.getId()));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Incompatible types. Required Long but 'map' was inferred to Mono<R>: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono<R> conforms to Long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do

```
Mono<Long> legalPersonDB = legalPersonJson.map(legalPerson -> find(legalPerson.getId()))
```

You will still need to subscribe to the Mono in order for it to execute.